# Using docker to be independent from Windows Updates

Tags: windows, docker, windows-update

Our partners want to see information about which of the Windows Updates are compatible with our application.
Of course, this is huge amount of work to test all Windows updates.

I thought that we can use Docker to containerize our application and ask all our partners to use same Docker image. So we will periodically test our app with new bunch of updates and send new docker image to all our partners.

I'm new in Docker and I'm not sure that this is a problem that can be solved by it. Is process running in Docker independent from Windows Updates installed on host machine? Is it good idea to use Docker for this purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a good idea. In general - Containerized application deployment is a great idea. You setup, test and validate the environment and you are pretty sure about its stability.

> Is process running in Docker independent from Windows Updates
>   installed on host machine?

For Windows container using virtualization technology and are independent of updates in host system.

Comment: So I can achieve this only using Hyper-V container type?

Comment: You dont have to care about that. It is Docker engine who will. There are few options for Windows: using VirtualBox or using HyperV (maybe some other). In all cases, your container is well isolated

Comment: There is one more option - Windows Server Containers, which are less isolated as I understand.

Comment: Why not. I am not familiar with WSC, but there are plenty of containerization techniques. You choose whatever suites you best. Docker is probably most popular now and thus better supported.